# Is it true that java volatile accesses cannot be reordered?

Tags: java, compiler-optimization, volatile, jls

**Note**
By saying that a memory access can (or cannot) be reordered I meand that it can  be
reordered either by the compiler when emitting byte code byte or by the JIT when emitting 
machine code or by the CPU when executing out of order (eventually requiring barriers to prevent this) with respect to any other memory access.

---

If often read that accesses to `volatile` variables cannot be reordered due to the *Happens-Before relationship* (HBR).

I found that an HBR exists between every two consecutive (in program order) actions of
a given thread and yet they can be reordered.

Also a volatile access HB only with accesses on the same variable/field.

What I thinks makes the `volatile` not reorderable is this

> A write to a volatile field (§8.3.1.4) happens-before every subsequent read [of any thread]
>    of that field.

**If there are others threads** a reordering of the variables will becomes visible as in this
simple example

```
        volatile int a, b;            

Thread 1                Thread 2

a = 1;                  while (b != 2); 
b = 2;                  print(a);       //a must be 1
```

So is not the HBR itself that prevent the ordering but the fact that `volatile`  extends this relationship with other threads, **the presence of other threads is the element that prevent reordering**.
If the compiler could prove that a reordering of a volatile variable would not change the
program semantic it could reorder it **even if there is an HBR**.

If a volatile variable is never accessed by other threads than its accesses
could be reordered

```
      volatile int a, b, c;            

Thread 1                Thread 2

a = 1;                  while (b != 2); 
b = 2;                  print(a);       //a must be 1
c = 3;                  //c never accessed by Thread 2
```

I think `c=3` could very well be reordered before `a=1`, this quote from the specs
confirm this

> It should be noted that the presence of a happens-before relationship between
>   two actions does not necessarily imply that they have to take place in that order
>   in an implementation. If the reordering produces results consistent with a legal
>   execution, it is not illegal.

So I made these simple java programs

```
public class vtest1 {
   public static volatile int DO_ACTION, CHOOSE_ACTION;

   public static void main(String[] args) {

      CHOOSE_ACTION = 34;
      DO_ACTION = 1;
   }
}

public class vtest2 {
   public static volatile int DO_ACTION,  CHOOSE_ACTION;

   public static void main(String[] args) {

      (new Thread(){

         public void run() {

             while (DO_ACTION != 1);
             System.out.println(CHOOSE_ACTION);
         }
      }).start();

      CHOOSE_ACTION = 34;
      DO_ACTION = 1;
   }
}
```

In both cases both fields are marked as `volatile` and accessed with `putstatic`.
Since these are all the information the JIT has<sup>1</sup>, the machine code would be identical, 
thus the `vtest1` accesses will not be optimized<sup>2</sup>.

### **My question**

*Are volatile accesses really never reordered by specification or they could be<sup>3</sup>, but this is never done in practice?*
*If volatile accesses can never be reordered, what parts of the specs say so? and would this means that all volatile accesses are executed and seen in program order by the CPUs?*

<sup><sub>1</sub>Or the JIT can known that a field will never be accessed by other thread? If yes, how?.</sup>
<sup><sub>2</sub>Memory barriers will be present for example.</sup>
<sup><sub>3</sub>For example if no other threads are involved.</sup>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to be using notation from [JLS §17.4.5](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.4.5).

In your second example, (if you'll excuse my loose notation) you have

Thread 1 ordering:
hb(`a = 1`, `b = 2`)
hb(`b = 2`, `c = 3`)

Volatile guarantees:
hb(`b = 2`, `b != 2`)
hb(`a = 1`, access `a` for `print`)

Thread 2 ordering:
hb(`while(b != 2);`, `print(a)`)

and we have (emphasis mine)

> More specifically, if two actions share a happens-before relationship,
>   **they do not necessarily have to appear to have happened in that order
>   to any code with which they do not share a happens-before
>   relationship**. Writes in one thread that are in a data race with reads
>   in another thread may, for example, appear to occur out of order to
>   those reads.

There is no happens-before relationship between `c=3` and Thread 2. The implementation is free to reorder `c=3` to its heart's content.

Answer (score 2):

What the JLS says (from [JLS-8.3.1.4. volatile Fields](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.3.1.4)) is, in part, that

> The Java programming language provides a second mechanism, `volatile` fields, that is more convenient than locking for some purposes.
>
> A field may be declared `volatile`, in which case the Java Memory Model ensures that all threads see a consistent value for the variable ([§17.4](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.4)).

Which means the access **may** be reordered, but the results of any reordering must *eventually* be consistent (when accessed by another thread) with the original order. A field in a single threaded application wouldn't **need** locking (from `volatile` or `synchronization`).

Comment: You can't have temporarily observed reordering and still be sequential consistent. See for my answer of what the allowed behavior is regarding reordering and sequential consistency.

Answer (score 1):

The Java memory model provides sequential consistency (SC) for correctly synchronized programs. SC in simple terms means that if all possible executions of some program, can be explained by different executions in which all memory actions are executed in some sequential order and this order is consistent with the program order (PO) of each of the threads, then this program is consistent with these sequential executions; so it is sequential consistent (hence the name).

What this effectively means that the JIT/CPU/memory subsystem can reorder volatile writes and reads as much as it wants as long as there exists a sequential execution that could also explain the outcome of the actual execution. So the actual execution isn't that important.

If we look at the following example:

```
  volatile int a, b, c;            

  Thread 1                Thread 2

  a = 1;                  while (c != 1); 
  b = 1;                  print(b); 
  c = 1;
```

There is a happens before relation between `a=1` and `b=2` (PO), and a happens before relation between `c=2` and `c=3` (PO) and a happens before relation `c=1` and `c!=0` (Volatile variable rule) and a happens before relation between `c!=0` and `print(b)` (PO).

Since the happens before relation is transitive, there is a happens before relation between `a=1` and `print(b)`. So in that sense, it can't be reordered. However, there is nobody to prove that a reordering happened, so it can still be reordered.

Answer (score 0):

From [17.4. Memory Model of JLS](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.4)

> The memory model describes possible behaviors of a program. An implementation is free to produce any code it likes, as long as all resulting executions of a program produce a result that can be predicted by the memory model.
> *<sub>This provides a great deal of freedom for the implementor to perform a myriad of code transformations, including the reordering of actions and removal of unnecessary synchronization.</sub>*